# Cant get an Array of Objects parsed

Tags: sequelize.js

### What you are doing?

Hi, I'm trying to get an array of objects from the DB.

Model

```
checklist: {
 type: DataTypes.ARRAY(DataTypes.JSON),
 allowNull: true,
 defaultValue: []
}
```

Query

```
return Note.findAll({
  order: '_id ASC',
  attributes: [
   '_id',
   'checklist'
  ]
})
```

### What do you expect to happen?

An object like this:

```
"checklist": [
    {checked: true, text: "Shortening"},
    {checked:true, text: "Margarine"},
    {checked:false, text: "Canned Stewed Tomatoes"},
    {checked:true, text: "Onions"}
  ]
```

### What is actually happening?

I'm getting an array of strings

```
"checklist": [
    "{\"checked\":true,\"text\":\"Shortening\"}",
    "{\"checked\":true,\"text\":\"Margarine\"}",
    "{\"checked\":false,\"text\":\"Canned Stewed Tomatoes\"}",
    "{\"checked\":true,\"text\":\"Onions\"}"
  ]
```

### Extra

I tried with a getter and setters, for get it works but when I try to update an element it throws an error.
Thanks!

### EDIT

Now I can get the data parsed with JSON.parse(), the issue now is when I'm updating something. This is what sequelize do: `"checklist"=ARRAY['{"checked":true,"text":"Shortening"}','{"‌​checked":true,"text"‌​:"Margarine"}','{"ch‌​ecked":false,"text":‌​"Canned Stewefd Tomatoes"}','{"checked":true,"text":"Onions"}']::JSON[]`

And this return error 500 with this text:

`SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1`

### FINAL EDIT

After checking the comments by yoogeeks I resolved to make a getter function in the model

```
checklist: {
      type: DataTypes.ARRAY(DataTypes.JSON),
      allowNull: true,
      defaultValue: [],
      get() {
        const data = this.getDataValue('checklist');
        const toSend = [];
        data.forEach(val => {
          toSend.push(JSON.parse(val));
        });
        return toSend;
      }
    },
```

And this works for GET but when I tried to Update some record it still throws an error. Finally I resolved to put a little check to know if the checklist field is a string or not.

```
checklist: {
      type: DataTypes.ARRAY(DataTypes.JSON),
      allowNull: true,
      defaultValue: [],
      get() {
        const data = this.getDataValue('checklist');
        const toSend = [];
        data.forEach(val => {
          toSend.push(typeof val === 'string' ? JSON.parse(val) : val);
        });
        return toSend;
      }
    },
```

And this works pretty good.

I don't know why this happens but my theory is that when I update sequelize go to the model and make another GET to return the data but when it does this get the checklist field is still an array not a string, so thats why I was getting the `SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1`. If there is somebody who know what exactly is would be nice to learn :)

Thank you so much!!

**Dialect:** postgres
**Sequelize version:** 3.23.6

Comment: It's because SQL doesn't know objects. Sequelize 'stringifies' your objects to be stored as strings in your table. What you need is `JSON.parse()` to get your actual object back.

Comment: Thanks. Now I can get the data parsed, now the issue is when I'm updating something.
This is what sequelize do:

`"checklist"=ARRAY['{"checked":true,"text":"Shortening"}','{"checked":true,"text":"Margarine"}','{"checked":false,"text":"Canned Stewefd Tomatoes"}','{"checked":true,"text":"Onions"}']::JSON[]`

And I get a 500 error without details. Could you give me an advice? Thank you!

Comment: Can you update your question with your update code?

Comment: `Unexpected token o` is raised when trying to parse `[object Object]` as JSON. Hint: 'o' from object. Reason: Array['{}','{}','{}','{}'...] is not a valid JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After checking the comments by yoogeeks I resolved to make a getter function in the model

```
checklist: {
      type: DataTypes.ARRAY(DataTypes.JSON),
      allowNull: true,
      defaultValue: [],
      get() {
        const data = this.getDataValue('checklist');
        const toSend = [];
        data.forEach(val => {
          toSend.push(JSON.parse(val));
        });
        return toSend;
      }
    },
```

And this works for GET but when I tried to Update some record it still throws an error. Finally I resolved to put a little check to know if the checklist field is a string or not.

```
checklist: {
      type: DataTypes.ARRAY(DataTypes.JSON),
      allowNull: true,
      defaultValue: [],
      get() {
        const data = this.getDataValue('checklist');
        const toSend = [];
        data.forEach(val => {
          toSend.push(typeof val === 'string' ? JSON.parse(val) : val);
        });
        return toSend;
      }
    },
```

And this works pretty good.

I don't know why this happens but my theory is that when I update sequelize go to the model and make another GET to return the data but when it does this get the checklist field is still an array not a string, so thats why I was getting the SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1. If there is somebody who know what exactly is would be nice to learn :)

Comment: For me the type: DataTypes.ARRAY(DataTypes.JSON), did the trick, thanks a lot